# PHPExcel HTML-output remove thousands

Tags: formatting, phpexcel

I design a *.xlsx per MS-Excel, format numeric like

```
#'##0.00_
```

Thousands-char is `'` not `,` !

Per PHPExcel open the xlsx and insert some values (unformatted).

Save as a new file:

```
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->save($Filename);
```

When I open these file in Excel, is looks very good, right format.

But when I output in HTML there I can see the thousands `,` again.

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
echo PHPExcel_HTML_bereinigen($objWriter->generateHTMLHeader(true));
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(1); // only second Sheet
echo $objWriter->generateSheetData();
```

How can I force to format all numbers by `'` or without an thousands?

Version PHPExcel_1.8.0
(I have hundreds of files with hundreds of cells)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want without a thousands separator, then change your format mask to:

```
###0.00_
```

---

Otherwise, use

```
#,##0.00_
```

and set the thousands separator using

```
PHPExcel_Shared_String::setThousandsSeparator("'");
```

Comment: PHPExcel_Shared_String::setThousandsSeparator("'"); did a very good job! For both: xlxs and html output. Thanks!